# After splash screens, Moto G screen goes black. Stock recovery won't start either. What to do?

Tags: boot, motorola-moto-g

I have a one-year old Moto G (1st Gen) that suddenly today refuses to boot usefully (a boot loop? Not sure.), has a blank dark screen but backlight stays on. Tried to restart it using the power off button.

I get the splash screens & a startup vibrate but then the same dark screen.

Succeeded in getting it to the boot menu (Version 41.13; Battery OK; Device is locked; Status Code 0) using power + volume key press. If I try selecting recovery it reports "Boot up failed".

Selecting any of the other options on the boot menu just brings me back to the original dark screen + backlight.

Any other things I can try? Phone is out of warranty so trying doesn't hurt me.

If I keep the phone on the dark screen it gets warm. Not sure if that's merely the backlight or there's some hung processes running.

Ideas?

**Edit 1:**

Some more information:

Yes, I've an alternate phone that I can use in the meantime.

No custom ROMs etc. were ever installed on this phone or even attempted to be installed. The phone was purchased new without any contract. It is running the Stock Google-Motorola Android.

Have not tried installing any custom recovery MOds yet.

Tried contacting Motorola using their online chat and went through the troubleshooting steps he advised. Nothing fruitful. He has asked me to call their Level 2 Support. I will on Monday.

The only procedure I found to get into Safe Mode asks to keep the on screen soft power off  button long pressed and wait for a prompt. I cannot get an on screen power button so not sure how I can get into safe mode.

History before the problem occurred: Phone was in  a call in progress. Suddenly had a lot of popups warn that various applications were being terminated. After that it went into this blank screen unresponsive state. No recent phone drops or other mishaps.

The one thing that I have gotten to work from the boot menu is a menu item that shows the IMEI / Sr No. / SKU / Purchase Date in Bar Code Format and Text.

**Edit 2:**

More Progress. Got fastboot. Posting some basic output below. If any other fastboot / adb commands will help in getting more debug info I'd love to know.

[image]

Comment: 1. Did you already phone Motorola for tech support? Do this before you install a custom recovery. 2. What version of Android is installed? 3. Are you running Google/Motorola Android, or a custom ROM? 4. Have you tried installing a custom recovery such as ClockworkMod? 5. Have you tried replacing Google/Motorola Android with a custom ROM? 6. Do you have a spare phone you can use for calls and SMSes in the meantime, or at least do you have a Google Voice or other VoIP account? 7. By the time you see the boot animation, you can use `adb shell`. Use `adb shell` then enter `ps`. What's the output?

Comment: And finally: What country and city do you live in? (Please put this in your profile.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put in answers to my questions as well as some progress updates. Every time you edit, it bumps your question to the top of the homepage, potentially getting your question more views.

Comment: Let me add:  Even if your phone is out of warranty, you may still be eligible for free telephone tech support.

Comment: And: 8. What are the most recent changes you made to the phone before the problem started? When? Did you drop it on the floor? 9. Is there some way (maybe holding down some buttons) to force a first-generation Moto G to boot up onto safe mode? Safe mode is not the same as recovery.

Comment: A)  I found some [instructions](http://www.mobiany.com/how-to-use-safe-mode-on-the-motorola-moto-g-through-the-hardware-keys.html) on you might be able to boot into safe mode in your situation.  But I don't know if the instructions are correct or not; and, even if they are, they might apply to the 2nd-generation Moto G only.  B)  If you can't get into Safe Mode, phone Motorola level 2 support.

Comment: C)  If that doesn't work:  Improve your question's title.  I suggest:  "After splash screens, Moto G screen goes black.  Stock recovery won't start either.  What to do?"  Also edit your phone's Android version into the question's body text; I presume it's 4.3.  Also do `adb shell` then enter `ps`, and provide the output.  D)  Ping me again.  E)  While you wait, I dunno whether or not [this](http://elinux.org/Android_Booting) might help you.

Comment: F)  If Motorola can't help you at all, then while you wait for further replies here, you might also want to do `adb backup` and then to try installing a custom recovery like CWM.  I don't know much about custom recovery images, though, and so I have no idea whether or not the installation could backfire and damage the phone further.

Comment: @unforgettableid Did call Motorola support. They are not of much use. The price they want me to pay for support is close to the price of a new phone. So that option is out.

Comment: @unforgettableid: Those instructions seem wrong. They start by asking me to remove the battery. The phone does not have a removable battery. Too bad.

Comment: @unforgettableid adb itself does not work. I can only get fastboot to work.  So I cannot try `adb shell` nor `adb backup`

Comment: I am no Android expert, and don't know enough to advise you what to do next.  You can keep on editing the question as your research progresses; each edit will bump the question to the top of the homepage.  Or you can try asking for help in some other venues.  Or you can do both.