# Using adb to backup data on an unbootable & non-rooted phone that does not have USB Debugging turned on

Tags: adb, boot, data-recovery, usb-debugging

I have a phone (Moto G) that won't boot & I had not turned the USB Debugging on when it used to boot correctly. The motivation is to use `adb` to get a full dump of the data on the phone before I try to resurrect it using `fastboot` commands that might be potentially data-destructive.

Is it still possible to somehow connect with `adb` from a PC + USB cable or it that option impossible now that I cannot access the menus that let me turn USB Debugging on?

Additional details of the problem I've posted on [this related Android Stackexchange thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/108992/after-splash-screens-moto-g-screen-goes-black-stock-recovery-wont-start-eithe)

Of course, if there's any way to backup a phone without using `adb`, that is welcome too. But I haven't seen anything like that yet.

Edit:

Phone isn't totally bricked. I get the initial splash screens of the Manufacturer's boot logo etc. & then it even does that initial vibrate. After that it goes blank (but backlight stays on) & just waits for ever.

If I connect it to a charger the LED blink & on-screen charging splash screen is also visible with the Charge %.

`fastboot` can connect to the phone but I haven't gotten `adb` to connect yet.

Comment: Can your phone boot into Recovery, or is the phone bricked (no display, no led, power button vibration, etc)? In the former case, some Recoveries allows access to ADB(default enabled).

Comment: Thanks @Firelord Phone isn't totally bricked. I get the initial splash screens of the Manufacturer's boot logo etc. & then it even does that initial vibrate. After that it goes blank (but backlight stays on) & just waits for ever.  I've edited my Question to reflect this.

Comment: I can get to the boot menu but the recovery option from the boot menu doesn't do anything & I get a "Boot up Failed" message.

Comment: I could not understand "Cannot Access Menus". Will it be possible to tell the reason why you're attempting ADB with the phone (in its current condition)? Could it be the data recovery you want to perform, or something else?

Comment: @Firelord: Exactly. Basically, the phone doesn't work and all the `fastboot` commands I've seen recommended as fixes all advise that a full backup first is safest. And all the backup commands I can see are `adb` based. That's why I'd want to get the phone to interact via `adb` if at all possible before I start running any `fastboot flash` or `fastboot erase` commands on it.

Comment: I advise an overhaul of the question, now that the goal is clear here. If you mention the reason, a reader will then think from the perspective of recovering data (could be some tools that won't need ADB at all). Also add the data-recovery tag in your question. That said, have you looked under the vast repository of questions tagged by [tag:data-recovery]? Please have a look if you've not done so (until I or somebody else can find something useful).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23895/discussion-between-firelord-and-curious-cat).

Comment: @Firelord: Thanks! I've overhauled the question like you suggested. How do we continue over chat?